# How to become a Theoretical Computer Scientist

Tags: soft-question, career

I am a computer science graduate from India. I have worked in a reputed software company for 10 months only to discover that my area of interest is something else. So I resigned from there and I am presently preparing for GATE 2014 which is due in a few days. Now I have the following doubts in my mind : 
 1. Is it sufficient and necessary to get into a reputed college in India through GATE ? 
 2. Are there any alternatives to pursue a career in Theoretical CS ? 
 3. How about foreign universities for this career path ?

Please provide me some career guidelines. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Come to the U.S. as a contractor. http://www.modis.com/locations/ Make enough money to travel at your leisure and do TCS for personal fulfillment unburdened with the poor working conditions that many university faculty face.

Comment: I think this question might find a better home on [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) as pointed out in Suresh's answer. If you want, ping me with a comment or flag and I can migrate this question there.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev : Yes. Please migrate it. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You asked three questions:

- Q1 is really out of scope for this forum: it relates to GATE and how you gain admission to Indian grad schools.
- Q2 I interpret as "do I need a graduate degree to study theoretical computer science". In general, of course the answer is "no", but the discipline of studying at the grad level (with the access to professors and other grad students) is hard to replace with a self-study unless you're supremely motivated.
- Q3: of course you can apply to foreign universities for graduate studies: again, you might find it useful to peruse [academia.stackexchange.com](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) for a plethora of information on how to go about doing this.